# Error "avr-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory" When Compiling Script

Tags: arduino-uno, ide, compilation-errors

Whenever I try to compile a script, the Arduino IDE throws the error `avr-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`. I've already tried reinstalling the IDE, changing the board version in the board manager to 1.6.21, and deleting the Arduino15 folder under `AppData/Local/Arduino15`.
This problem appeared suddenly - one compilation worked, and two minutes later, nothing would compile - and occurs across all scripts that I've tried.

I'm working from Windows 10 and compiling for an Arduino Uno.

Comment: Antivirus playing merry hell with your installation?

Comment: Just checked my activity log and that's exactly what's going on. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that McAfee's Host Intrusion Prevention had decided to start blocking `avr-g++.exe`. Not sure why it did so all of a sudden, but it's an easy fix once you know where to look. Anyone finding this in the future should be sure to check their antivirus logs to see if the compiler's executable is being blocked.

Comment: I seem to be having this issue as well, but it's not clear to me what I should do about it. Do I disable McAfee and then reinstall? Do I set the executable as an exception? I've never modified anything in McAfee so I need more information for this easy fix. Much obliged!

Comment: Setting the executable sounds reasonable. This part is really more to do with McAfee. I would expect McAfee's documentation is sufficient to answer this, but if not https://superuser.com/ is probably the place to ask that sort of thing.